# Wix 3.5 to create folder outside of Installation Root

Tags: installation, wix, wix3.5

How can i use Wix v3.5 to create folders outside of my normal installation path?

Below create folder for my root installation.

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">

  <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="FolderName">

  </Directory>
 </Directory>
```

eg, if user select c:, then this will install to c:\FolderName

I need to create additional folders in C: itself. How can i achieve that?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from having another Directory element defined side by side with INSTALLLOCATION. Make sure appropriate components then reference that folder, and you'll end up having necessary files there:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="FolderName">
   ...
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="ANOTHERLOCATION" Name="SecondFolderName">
   ...
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

UPDATE: a sample with CreateFolder element is added below.

```
<DirectoryRef Id="ANOTHERLOCATION">
  <Component Id="comp1" Guid="GUID-HERE" KeyPath="yes">
    <CreateFolder />
  </Component>
</Directory>
```

Comment: But I have something as below but it's not creating
 <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">

      <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="FolderName" />
      <Directory Id="SecondFolderNameLocation" Name="SecondFolderName" />
      <Directory Id="ThirdFolderNameLocation" Name="ThirdFolderName" />
 
    </Directory>      
    </Directory>

Comment: I forgot to say i just want to create those empty directories not referencing them in component or anywhere.

Comment: In case you'd like to have empty folders created, you'll have to author a component for each, place it under the desired folder and author a <CreateFolder/> element, otherwise the folder won't be created.

Comment: How to assign a path value to `ANOTHERLOCATION` for example if I want it to be `D:\MyFolder1\MyFolder2`?

Comment: @MykhailoSeniutovych, just like any other property: `msiexec.exe /i "C:\Example.msi" ANOTHERLOCATION="D:\MyFolder1\MyFolder2"`

Comment: Can I do it through code? If it was a property I would do it like this:
<Property Id="ORDERSFOLDER" Value="D:\MyFolder1\MyFolder2" />

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can, but as `<SetProperty ... After="CostFinalize">`. Haven't worked with Windows Installer for quite a while. Try it out, don't just trust the suggestion :)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372403(v=vs.85).aspx